# sparse matrix list .cat.codes invalid syntax error

Tags: matrix, syntax, syntax-error, sparse-matrix

i am having trouble with the piece of code below as part of an tutorial where we have to create a sparse matrix from 2 columns by first converting them into a list each. I am getting an unknown syntax error and really not sure how to resolve this. I would much appreciate any help please.

**Code:**

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

customers = list(np.sort(grouped_purchased.CustomerID.unique())) # Get our unique customers
products = list(grouped_purchased.StockCode.unique()) # Get our unique products that were purchased
quantity = list(grouped_purchased.Quantity) # All of our purchases

rows = grouped_purchased.CustomerID.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories = ['customers']).cat.codes

## Get the associated row indices

cols = grouped_purchased.StockCode.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories = ['products']).cat.codes

## Get the associated column indices

purchases_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix((quantity, (rows, cols)), shape=(len(customers), len(products)))

**Error:**

File "", line 10

```
cols = grouped_purchased.StockCode.astype(CategoricalDtype(categories = ['products']).cat.codes
   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: missing `)` in this and the previous

Comment: thanks hpaulj the original code from the tutorial is slightly different as follows but it was not working: rows = grouped_purchased.CustomerID.astype('category', categories = customers).cat.codes 
# Get the associated row indices
cols = grouped_purchased.StockCode.astype('category', categories = products).cat.codes

Comment: I added a bracket after ['customers']) as follows ['customers'])) and also after ['products'])) but i am now getting other value error: ValueError: negative row index found